# How to log CPU usage but only when it is high or touching certain treshold ? (+ formatting)

Tags: shell-script, logs, io-redirection, text-formatting, top

How can we log CPU usage but *only* when there is a process(s) with utilization above certain threshold (for example 30% or more) ?

What i am trying to achieve (with shell script) are more or less like this

```
currCPU = $(cpu-checker)
while true; do
 if(($currCPU >= 80)); then
  echo "$(date +%F %R)"
  $(top -n 1 | head -n 12  | tail -n 3 | replace "\n" "\n  ") >> someFile.log
 fi
 sleep 2.5
done
# (cpu-checker) and (replace "\n" "\n  ") are the
# problematic part
```

with the expected output will be (sort of) like this

```
2020-08-03 02:31
  16979 root      20   0   43188   4280   3396 R 104.3  0.0   0:00.06 super-process-1
  1     root      20   0  225760   9428   6648 S   0.0  0.0   0:08.94 systemd
  2     root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 kthreadd
  4     root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H

2020-08-03 09:44
  16979 root      20   0   43188   4280   3396 R  93.3  0.0   0:00.06 another-process
  1     root      20   0  225760   9428   6648 S   0.0  0.0   0:08.94 systemd
  2     root      20   0       0      0      0 S 102.0  0.0   0:00.04 random-proce
  4     root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

I have tried few things, with all case tried on a Ubuntu Server 16.04.4 (as this is the only environment that i have)

So far, i have not found anything yet for the `cpu-checker` part, but for the formatting part (`replace "\n" "\n  "`) i have tried to use `tr "\n" "\n  "` and `sed G` with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

```
sed 's/^/ /'
```

replaces each starting of a line with a space.

```
uptime | sed 's/.*load average: //;s/,.*//'
```

gives you the load average of the last minute as a fraction (CPU%). This may a measurement for how busy your system is.

As @Paul_Pedant suggested in his comment:

```
top -b -n 1 | awk '/%Cpu/ || $1 == "PID" || $1 ~ /^[0-9]+/; NR >= 12 { exit; }'
```

gives you the real CPU %.

Or, if you are adventurous and don't mind some Python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep


last_idle = last_total = 0
with open('/proc/stat') as f:
    fields = [float(column) for column in f.readline().strip().split()[1:]]
idle, total = fields[3], sum(fields)
idle_delta, total_delta = idle - last_idle, total - last_total
last_idle, last_total = idle, total
sleep(1)
with open('/proc/stat') as f:
    fields = [float(column) for column in f.readline().strip().split()[1:]]
idle, total = fields[3], sum(fields)
idle_delta, total_delta = idle - last_idle, total - last_total
last_idle, last_total = idle, total
utilisation = 100.0 * (1.0 - idle_delta / total_delta)
print('%5.1f' % utilisation)
```

reads `/proc/stat` and does the calculation for you.

```
date '+%F %R'
```

gives exactly the same output as

```
echo "$(date '+%F %R')"
```

And you may want to redirect the output to your log.

and finally,

```
top -bn 1 | sed '1,/PID *USER/d' | head -3
```

is probably more reliable than your `tail` and `head` combination.

Comment: Also, use the `top -b` option. Without that, top sends all the cursor positioning and highlighting terminal codes, which makes the piped output kind of hard to process. (Try: `top -n1 | cat -vet | more` to see.)

Comment: The 'load average' is not the CPU usage. It is the average number of processes in the scheduler queue. You need to search for the RE ^%Cpu. I would `top -b -n 1 | awk '/%Cpu/ || $1 == "PID" || $1 ~ /^[0-9]+/; NR >= 12 { exit; }'